# c# app to take in excel document, and list all pivot tables on each sheet and refresh in its own thread. (faster refresh using multi threading)

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

Is it possible to create an multi threaded application,

The lists all the pivot tables in an excel document,

And fires a new thread to refresh each pivot table.

Currently a applicatoin.refreshall takes 3hrs.

I also do not think that vba code can be mulithreaded.

Any ideas welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that making this process multithreaded would necessarily help.  3 hours is a pretty long time for *anything* - I suspect you have other problems with this excel document.  How big is the file?